# Can't add foreign key after table has been created

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, alter-table

I'm trying to add a foreign key to a table I already made called orderline. I want the foreign key to be `item_id` from my `items` table but I get the error

> "Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Here are my tables

```
create table items(
    item_id int(3),
    title char(50),
    artist char(50),
    unit_price decimal(4,2),
    on_hand int(3)
);

create table orderline(
    order_id int(3), 
    item_id int(3), 
    order_qty int(2)
);
```

and my query

```
ALTER TABLE orderline 
ADD constraint fk_item_id
FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES items(item_id);
```